# .NET Google Drive API - Get files with parent folder

Tags: c#, .net, api, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Is there any possible way to get the list of files with parent folder name and without making additional queries?

My `Files.List()` code sample:

```
var sheets = new List<File>();
var sheetsRequest = Service.Files.List();
sheetsRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, owners, parents)";
sheetsRequest.Q = $"mimeType = '{mimeType}' and name = '{name}'";
sheetsRequest.PageSize = 500;
var sheetsFeed = await sheetsRequest.ExecuteAsync();
while (sheetsFeed.Files != null)
{
    foreach (var file in sheetsFeed.Files)
    {
        sheets.Add(file);
    }
    if (sheetsFeed.NextPageToken == null)
        break;
    sheetsRequest.PageToken = sheetsFeed.NextPageToken;
    sheetsFeed = await sheetsRequest.ExecuteAsync();
}
return sheets;
```

Because for now I making `GetFileParentDirAsync` call for each `File` using following method (and it's very slow):

```
public async Task<string> GetFileParentDirAsync(File file)
{
    return await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var folderName = string.Empty;

        if (file.Parents?.First() == null) return folderName;

        var parentId = file.Parents.First();
        var parentRequest = Service.Files.Get(parentId);
        var parentResponse = await parentRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        folderName = parentResponse.Name;

        return folderName;
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the sample code *in the question* rather than via a link. It would also help if it were a complete example rather than a snippet - aside from anything else, that would show the version number (via the `using` directives.)

Comment: In general though, I'd expect this to be API-specific but language agnostic.

Comment: Again, please include code *in the question*. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for advice on asking good questions.

Comment: Ah, so just to be clear, you're not trying to find *files within a particular parent*, but just the name of the parent?

Comment: To clarify further - do you have lots of *different* parent folders? If not, just adding a cache of parent ID -> folder name would go a long way, I suspect... and then if you've got lots of files, work out all the folder IDs you want to look up, and write a batch GET request.